# Facebook OpenGraph sees my meta as type Website instead of Product

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph

I am trying to add [OpenGraph product meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product/) to my page. The resulting tags are:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product">
<meta property="og:title" content="3 Night Cruise Sampler Cruise on the Pacific Aria">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://test.abcde.com/cruise/paa626">
<meta property="og:image" content="//static.abcde.com/OzC/www/images/Cruise/Large/1198.jpg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Cruises">
<meta property="product:product_link" content="https://test.abcde.com/cruise/paa626">
<meta property="product:purchase_limit" content="0">
```

However when I go and test with the [Facebook Open Graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) it tells me I am missing a title for an object type of **website**. The exact errors are:

> Object at URL "https://test.abcde.com/cruise/paa626" of type
>   "website" is invalid because a required property "og:title" of type
>   "string" was not provided.

As I am specifying that the type is product why is that being ignored and I also do have a **og:title**. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fired surely this error: `Share App ID Missing`. `fb:app_id` is a required parameter, missing of it could cause further error / misinterpretations.

Try to add `fb:app_id` and `fb:admin` - i guess after this you will get rid of the error you describe.